# raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Tags: python-3.x, rest

Im trying to model some code based on this project. https://auth0.com/blog/developing-restful-apis-with-python-and-flask/#bootstrapping-flask

This is my first REST API in python.  Here is the code.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class Product():
  def __init__(self, ident, name, description, category):
      self.ident = ident
      self.name = name
      self.description = description
      self.category = category

  def __repr__(self):
      return '<Expense(name={self.description!r})>'.format(self=self)

class ProductSchema(Schema):
      ident = fields.Str()
      name = fields.Str()
      category = fields.Str()
      description = fields.Str()
```

index.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from server.model.product import Product, ProductSchema

app = Flask(__name__)

products=[Product('a','b','c','d')]


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
      return "Hello, World!"

@app.route("/products", methods=['POST'])
def add_product():
    product = ProductSchema().load(request.get_json())
    products.append(product.data)
    return "", 204

@app.route("/products")
def get_products():
    schema = ProductSchema(many=True)
    return jsonify(products)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

However when I try to do a http GET request for /products I get the error in the description.

Comment: What you try to do GET or POST?

Comment: I try to do the GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1. `products` type is list and jsonify is not result list because is not security.
2. `Product()` object is class and you need return dict.

change you code with this:

```
import json
@app.route("/products")
def get_products():
    schema = ProductSchema(many=True)
    return json.dumps([p.__dict__ for p in prodacts])
```

or

```
from flask import Response
import json

    @app.route("/products")
    def get_products():
        schema = ProductSchema(many=True)
        return Response(json.dumps([p.__dict__ for p in prodacts]), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: This works but it looks like it doesnt use marshmallow to serialize